Apex (de)serialize JSON with Map<String, Object> properties
My Apex code talks to the OpenAI API which has a Message object.
This is the Apex Wrapper class for Message:
public class Message {
  public String id;
  public String role;
  public String run_id;
  public List<Content> content = new List<Content>();
  public Map<String, Object> metadata = new Map<String, Object>();
}

JSON.serialize and deserialize() fail because Apex JSON cannot cope with type Object.
Is there a workaround for that?

Are you going to be actually using that metadata? If not, why not simply leave it out of your Message class?

Also, the API documentation is frustratingly vague on what the metadata map actually is. Given it says the values are a max of 512 characters, would not a Map<String, String> be appropriate?

You are correct in saying that Apex is limited regarding the deserialize method, but serialization works just fine. I think the workaround is to use the deserializeUntyped method instead. You'll get a Map<String, Object> and can cast the types as needed (dynamically).
Taking your example (without the Content object):
public class Message {
  public String id;
  public String role;
  public String run_id;
  public Map<String, Object> metadata = new Map<String, Object>();
}

Message m = new Message();
m.id = '1234';
m.metadata = new Map<String, Object>{ 'hello' => 'world' };

String jso = JSON.serialize(m);

Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jso);
System.debug(data);
// {id=null, metadata={hello=world}, role=null, run_id=null}

System.debug(data.get('id'));
// 1234

System.debug(data.get('metadata'));
// {hello=world}

Map<String, Object> md = (Map<String, Object>) data.get('metadata');
System.debug(md.get('hello'));
// world

// This one fails with a specific type:
//System.debug(JSON.deserialize(jso, Message.class));

